# NSTreeController, arrangedObjects -- How does NSOutlineVIew Column get data from bindings?

Tags: xcode4.2, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

Using XCode 4.2 with ARC.

I'm trying to write a custom view for a hierachy of stuff.  I'm using NSTreeController.

I also have a standard outline view.  My nodes have a property 'name' which is an NSAttributedString.

In my standard outline view using bindings, I have bound the column to the tree controller's "arrangedObjects.name"  IB Complains that this is an attributed string, not a string but nevertheless it works, displays properly, and can be edited (for font and color, for example).

On the other hand, in my custom view if I try to bind arrangedObjects.name to anything, it is an error -- "[<_NSControllerTreeProxy 0x1003389c0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name."

This is, of course, in agreement with the documentation, but not in agreement with what NSOutlineView does!

I can probably do what I want with arrangedObjects.childNodes and recursion and other code, but

1. How does OutlineView do it?  and,
2. Why does IB give me a red warning for an attributed string going to an outline view column?